# UnionFS and SSHFS for Windows

Tags: windows, sshfs

Is there something like a UnionFS for Windows?

My usecase: read-only mount a remote filesystem via SSH and have something like UnionFS handle the writes.

I know this is possible on Unix, how 'bout Windows?

Answer (score 3):

See if [Dokan SSHFS](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-sshfs) fills the gap.

Also see the question on its stability posted on StackOverflow here: [How stable is dokan sshfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854424/how-stable-is-dokan-sshfs)