# How stable is dokan sshfs?

Tags: windows, driver, sshfs, dokan

People have reported BSOD on windows 7 (64bit) http://dokan-dev.net/en/2009/04/06/the-next-release-of-dokan-library/. For some reason unknown to me, my explorer on winxp sp3 (32bit) gets shaky and at time freezes if I do lots of browsing via doken SSHFS drive. Have you faced any issues lately with sshfs doken driver? Just wanted to get your opinion on its stability?

Comment: If I understood correctly the question, I think that this belongs to SuperUser.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, BSOD on x64 in general, with 100% certainty on my Windows Vista x64, everytime !

The shaky is because it continuously syncs the client fs with yours. Your connection is too slow  and/or the operating system and/or explorer is improperly threaded. As soon as you disconnect sshfs, you're back to normal.

**Edit:**
There is a new edition of it out for x64 as of February 2010.
Now it works on x64, but you have to replace the executables the installer installs with the one supplied in the zip file.